# Split body of text into sentences but keep punctuation?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm attempting to produce a human readable wiki-like difference between 2 bodies of html laden text. I'm using diff-lcs and the first step is separating the string (array of characters) into an array of sentences, but keep their punctuation.

```
"I am a lion. Hear me roar! Where is my cub? Never mind, found him.".magic_split(/[.?!]/)
# => "I am a lion." "Hear me roar!" "Where is my cub?" "Never mind, found him."
```

This should do the trick

```
"I am a lion. Hear me roar! Where is my cub? Never mind, found him.".gsub(/[.?!]/, '\1|').split('|')
```

Except gsub appears to have trouble inserting the characters `.?!`. Instead it's returning this

```
"I am a lion| Hear me roar| Where is my cub| Never mind, found him|"
```

What's the easiest way to do a non-destructive split? As in it keeps the characters it splits by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that should be `\0`

```
>> string = "I am a lion. Hear me roar! Where is my cub? Never mind, found him."
>> string.gsub(/[.?!]/, '\0|') 
   # "I am a lion.| Hear me roar!| Where is my cub?| Never mind, found him.|"
```

Answer (score 13):

`scan` should do the trick (throw `strip` in there to get rid of trailing spaces).

```
s = "I am a lion. Hear me roar! Where is my cub? Never mind, found him."
s.scan(/[^\.!?]+[\.!?]/).map(&:strip) # => ["I am a lion.", "Hear me roar!", "Where is my cub?", "Never mind, found him."]
```

Comment: How would you edit this if you wanted to catch a sentence ending in '...' Something like "I am a lion. Hear me roar! Where is my cub? Never mind, found him..."

Comment: I've edited it as follows: `text.scan(/[^\.!?]+[\.!?]+/).map(&:strip)` The only problem that remains is catching a final sentence without a period: "I am a lion. Hear me roar! What is your name? Don't judge me", misses the final "don't judge me"

Comment: Working solution: `text.scan(/[^\.!?]+[\.!?]+|[^\.!?]+.\z/).map(&:strip)` (there is probably a more elegant way, but this is working). Input: "I am a lion... Hear me roar!! What is your name? Don't judge me" --> Output: "["I am a lion...", "Hear me roar!!", "What is your name?", "Don't judge me"]"